# Consistent graph drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, graph-theory

Is there a Javascript library that produces consistent graph drawings (e.g. graph theory style graphs) in browsers?

By consistent, I mean that it produces an unique graph (same orientation and same positions of nodes) given a set of inputs (i.e. configurations of the nodes and edges).

Comment: Which Javascript library *doesn't* produce consistent graph drawings? Am I missing something?

Comment: @meetamit, http://www.graphdracula.net/, looking at the example, if you hit 'redraw' button (presumably the inputs are the same), it gives you different drawings of the same graph. Drawing using Javascript is new to me, but some other tools I've used (e.g. Mathematica) don't draw consistently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most graph layout algorithms (except the completely deterministic ones like grid layout or the Reingold-Tilford tree layout) use some kind of random initialization. Since there is no way to set the seed of the random number generator explicitly in Javascript, it is very hard to coerce graph layout algorithms into being completely deterministic. Your best bet is probably to take an existing library in Javascript that can draw graphs (such as d3.js) and replace the calls to `Math.random` and similar to a pure Javascript-based random number generator for which you can set the seed explicitly. Setting the seed to the same value should then ensure that the same layout is generated for the same graph every time you run the algorithm.

Implementations of Javascript random number generators can be found [here](http://github.com/BrianRamsay/Randomizer), [here](http://www.karlbunyan.co.uk/2008/12/repeatable-random-numbers-in-javascript.aspx) or [here](http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html).

Comment: You beat me to this answer - +1

Comment: Thanks, I've added that to my answer.